# Backbone.js internal triggerEvents function. How is it optimized?

Tags: javascript, performance, backbone.js

I was reading through the Backbone source code and I came across the triggerEvents function, which is used internally. The function includes the comment "A difficult-to-believe, but optimized internal dispatch function'. I was curious if anyone with more knowledge of the internal mechanics of JavaScript could explain in exactly what way this is optimized. The function along with the comment:

```
// A difficult-to-believe, but optimized internal dispatch function for
// triggering events. Tries to keep the usual cases speedy (most internal
// Backbone events have 3 arguments).
var triggerEvents = function(events, args) {
  var ev, i = -1, l = events.length, a1 = args[0], a2 = args[1], a3 = args[2];
  switch (args.length) {
    case 0: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx); return;
    case 1: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1); return;
    case 2: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1, a2); return;
    case 3: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.call(ev.ctx, a1, a2, a3); return;
    default: while (++i < l) (ev = events[i]).callback.apply(ev.ctx, args); return;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Function.prototype.apply` is essentially the same as `Function.prototype.call`, with a little more logic that breaks up the arguments array into individual arguments. Using `call` explicitly instead of `apply` this way is *slightly* more optimized because it only goes through that extra logic if there's more than 3 arguments.

See: [ECMAScript 5 call](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) vs [apply spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3)

Either way, in ECMAScript 6 both functions will have tail call optimization, which essentially 'recycles' the function instead of making an additional call to the same function.

[ECMAScrip 6 call](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-function.prototype.call) & [apply spec](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-function.prototype.apply)